# How to return typeorm union type of two entities?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have two tables in a mysql database with typeorm and nestjs.

Lets say:

```
@Entity({ name: 'timeline_comments' })
export class ExampleEntityOne extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  something: string;
}
```

```
@Entity({ name: 'timeline_comments' })
export class ExampleEntityTwo extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  something_else: string;
}
```

then I have the service that returns the following:

```
type BothDefinitions = ExampleEntityOne & ExampleEntityTwo

class MyService {
  constructor(
@InjectRepository(ExampleEntityOne)
    private readonly exampleEntityOne: Repository<ExampleEntityOne>,
@InjectRepository(ExampleEntityTwo)
    private readonly exampleEntityTwo: Repository<ExampleEntityTwo>,
  ) {}
  async getValues(exampleOneIds: number[], exampleTwoIds: number[]): Promise<BothDefinitions[]> {
    const fromExampleOne = await this.exampleEntityOne.find(exampleOneIds)
    const fromExampleTwo = await this.exampleEntityOne.find(exampleTwoIds)
    const results = [...fromExampleOne, ...fromExampleTwo].map(x => {
      return {
        ...x,
        something: x.something || null,
        something_else: x.something_else || null
      }
    })
   return results
  }
}
```

This code will throw the following error in typescript:

type {id, something} is missing the following properties from type 'ExampleEntityOne': hasId, save, remove, softRemove, and 2 more.

and i dont need to return this methods, can I define this method returns only with the values of this entities without the need to rewrite this type definition (interface BothDefinitions { id, something, something_else... }) ? by just using the & or | from typescript?